# jQuery/HTML5 modal video if autoplay is present play video

Tags: jquery, html, video, autoplay

To make it easier to understand please take a look at the Codepen:
http://codepen.io/hennysmafter/pen/YqmLKR

The codepen is a simpler version of the actual code with only the parts that are necessary!

In the codepen you have two popups one popup has a video element **with** autoplay and the other has a video element **without** autoplay

On document ready all video elements on the page are paused **this cannot be changed because of other videos in the actual code**

Now I just need to have the code adapted so that:

1. On click popup opens and class is added `opened` (already there)
2. If video element inside popup has autoplay then play the video (not working)
3. Or no autoplay so do nothing

   ```
   if ($('.modal-box.opened').find('video').attr(autoplay) == true) {
       $('.modal-box.opened').find('video').each(function() {
         $(this).get(0).play();
   });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've two somewhat common mistakes: You **only used 1 equals sign** in the part where you check if `autoplay` is true.

A single `=` is used for setting variables where as two is used for checking equality.

**Edit:** You are also attempting to use traditional HTML style attribute checking on a jQuery object. To check an attribute in jQuery, you need to use `.attr(attributeName)`

Therefore, the correct line would be `if ($('.modal-box.opened').find('video').attr(autoplay) == true) {`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the code but now the videos will no longer work at all. I don't necessarily want to keep this code I just need to have a code that checks if the word `autoplay` is present inside the `<video>` tag. And I think it ain't working as it is looking for `<video autoplay="true">` instead of `<video autoplay>`. Deserves a upvote however. But not marking as accepted just yet.

Comment: I've edited the post with more info.

Comment: I have no clue why but it ain't working I am going to put it in Codepen! Not saying your answer is wrong because I think it is not it's something else I think!

Comment: I added a codepen for you to see http://codepen.io/hennysmafter/pen/YqmLKR

Comment: So I just rewritten the question to make thing easier to understand. Thanks for helping.