# How to target autoplay attribute in HTML 5 Video element inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a HTML 5 video element inside a modal window. Now I need a check that if modal is opened and video element has autoplay then play the video. If the video does not have the attribute autoplay then do not play the video.

http://codepen.io/hennysmafter/pen/YqmLKR

For the full code look at the Codepen above please.

```
<video id="somevid" controls autoplay loop>
 <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

So it needs to target the `autoplay` and it cannot use the ID field from the video it should target the video element inside `id: popup1` see Codepen!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();     
            if ($('.modal-box.opened').find('video').attr(autoplay) == true) {
                console.log('CLICK: ModalBox if Video Autoplay is true.');
            }
    });             
});
```

The code where the problem is above. Now I know this only gives me a log that is just for testing.

This code gives the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: autoplay is not defined

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the variable `autoplay` rather than the string `"autoplay"`, try updating your code to this:

```
if ($('.modal-box.opened').find('video').attr('autoplay') == true) {
  console.log('CLICK: ModalBox if Video Autoplay is true.');
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this instead:

```
if (($('.modal-box.opened').find('video').attr('autoplay') === 'autoplay')) {
  $('.modal-box.opened').find('video').get(0).play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. I forked a Codepen for you with your code. Too bad it ain't working could you look at it please. Thank you. How stupid forgot to put the Codepen in: http://codepen.io/hennysmafter/pen/EKqJGe?editors=1010

@illizian

Comment: I think it works. I can't believe it... Need to check it out a few more times. Will let you know in a minute...

Comment: Yes it works brilliantly. Thank you so much for going through the troubles in rewriting your code. I appreciate it. I up voted and I choose this one as the accepted answer.

Comment: I asked a similar question yesterday at SO. I now posted your answer as my own but I would really love it if you would post this answer there as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398260/jquery-html5-modal-video-if-autoplay-is-present-play-video
When you do I remove my answer immediately! If you don't I leave it for others to at least get a correct answer. I also leave a link to this post and I mention you as the answergiver.

Comment: @purple11111 I've flagged that question as a duplicate and pointed it at this one, it should take effect after review.

Comment: That is even better. I removed my answer as it was no longer necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the quotes around autoplay, like

```
if ($('.modal-box.opened').find('video').attr("autoplay") == true)
```

Moreover, it should perhaps be used prop("autoplay"), knowing that autoplay is a property

**EDIT : Autostart**

`$(this).get(0)` doesn't return the desired element, so you must recover the video again :

```
var video = $('.modal-box.opened').find('video');
if (video.prop("autoplay")) {
    video.get(0).play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried both in a new Codepen please take a look: http://codepen.io/hennysmafter/pen/MyNRLQ?editors=1010

@Loscillo

Comment: I went for the answer of Illizian and I believe you both are saying the same thing as he is recovering the video also. Therefore I cannot accept your answer as the accepted one but I do upvote you as it clearly deserves that. Furthermore I really want to thank you for taking the time in helping this poor old soul.

Comment: No problem, Illizian was faster ! Thank you for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

To check if autoplay is set:

```
var $video = $('.modal-box.opened').find('video');

if( typeof $video.attr('autoplay') === "string"){
    $video.get(0).play();
}
```

or to check if autoplay is not set:

```
if( typeof $video.attr('autoplay')  === "undefined"){
    //Logic here
}
```

Comment: This seems very promising but I am not sure where and how to insert it in the existing code?
Could you give the full IF function? That would make it so much easier. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey I just tried your code and it is working. It is really nice to know how to see the IF/Else work it is a eyeopener. It pains me to say that I already accepted a answer which is almost the same as yours. I wished I could accept more answers as the right one as this is clearly one of them! I will upvote it as that goes without saying and would like to thank you for taking all this time in helping a fellow on SO.

Comment: Hi, not a problem, just trying to help. I'm glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this Example 
I hope It would be helpful

> `[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/NbE9d/570/`

Comment: Thanks but it is Bootstrap modal. I will however try to take parts of the code and see if it works. If you want you can try it yourself in the Codepen.